# Releasing memory while processing huge amount of images

Tags: python, image, image-processing, airflow

I have dag in Airflow, dag processing docs with information for images and I run this dag for 500K docs, every docs contain url with image, downloaded image from this url (use multiprocessing.ThreadPool  for this), open with PIL.Image and predicted by neural net category for this image. I coded processing images in batches (5K images in each). How I can release memory when next batches start processing? In memory profiler, memory increase huge in generator function call (for img_batch, url_to_id_map in self.images_generator(img_index_docs_list) this string)

```
class ImagePredictingOp(BaseOperator):

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 mng_db,
                 mng_models_collection,
                 mng_image_index_collection,
                 *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImagePredictingOp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mng_db = mng_db
        self.mng_models_collection = mng_models_collection
        self.mng_image_index_collection = mng_image_index_collection
        self.is_scheduled = True


    def images_generator(self, docs):
        chunk_size = 5000
        gc.collect()
        del gc.garbage[:]
        for batch in range(0, len(docs), chunk_size):
            img_index_docs = docs[batch: batch + chunk_size]
            url_to_id_map = {doc['Url']: doc['_id'] for doc in img_index_docs}
            raw_img_list = ThreadPool(32).imap_unordered(self.get_raw_image, img_index_docs)
            img_indx_raw_for_predict = {url: raw_img for raw_img, url in raw_img_list}
            img_indx_for_predict = {url: img for url, img in img_indx_raw_for_predict.items() if img is not None}
            yield img_indx_for_predict, url_to_id_map

    def execute(self, context):
        models_collection = self.init_mng_collection(self.mng_models_collection)
        img_index_collection = self.init_mng_collection(self.mng_image_index_collection)
        model_id_list = self.get_mng_doc_models(models_collection)
        models_objects = self.get_trained_models_objects(model_id_list, models_collection)
        img_index_docs_list = self.get_mng_images_doc(img_index_collection)
        for img_batch, url_to_id_map in self.images_generator(img_index_docs_list):
            gc.collect()
            del gc.garbage[:]
            for prediction_model in models_objects:
                prediction_result = prediction_model.work(img_batch)
                self.put_to_mongo_result(prediction_result, prediction_model.name, url_to_id_map, img_index_collection)
```

This is memory_profiler result

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    54  319.652 MiB  319.652 MiB       @profile
    55                                 def execute(self):
    56  319.652 MiB    0.000 MiB           count = 0
    57  319.957 MiB    0.305 MiB           models_collection = self.init_mng_collection(self.mng_models_collection)
    58  319.957 MiB    0.000 MiB           img_index_collection = self.init_mng_collection(self.mng_image_index_collection)
    59  319.957 MiB    0.000 MiB           model_id_list = ['5d9de619929ea61c40ae6267']
    60 2143.152 MiB 1823.195 MiB           models_objects = self.get_trained_models_objects(model_id_list, models_collection)
    61 5196.199 MiB 3053.047 MiB           img_index_docs_list = self.get_mng_images_doc(img_index_collection)
    62 20555.500 MiB 7782.336 MiB           for img_batch, url_to_id_map in self.images_generator(img_index_docs_list):
    63 20555.500 MiB    0.000 MiB               count += 1
    64 20605.824 MiB    0.000 MiB               for prediction_model in models_objects:
    65 20606.246 MiB   90.785 MiB                   prediction_result = prediction_model.work(img_batch)
    66 20605.824 MiB    0.000 MiB                   self.put_to_img_index(prediction_result, prediction_model.name, url_to_id_map, img_index_collection)
    67 20605.824 MiB    0.000 MiB               if count == 2:
    68 20605.824 MiB    0.000 MiB                   break
```